# How can i save version before filesystemWatcher event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task to save versions of documents for specified directory and look for changes.

before each change i need to keep the CURRENT version of the file in other place.

but the filesystemWatcher doesnt help me here because its events is after the change...

what should i do ?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for the application that manages the documents, or do you have to come up with a solution without changing the application?

Comment: What version of Windows do you need to support - Volume Shadow Copy Service could help you out here.

Comment: chibacity : i need to do it via c#. not via shadow mechanism. - for the 1st question  :  i nee to detect manual changes in the file as if a person came to the folder and changed document. - so i need history. i dont want 3rd party softs. just what ive asked - c#.

Comment: Can you change the source code of the application managing the documents?

Comment: You would still want/need VSS for accessing open files.

Comment: I agree with Lloyd and chibacity - you're going to need to use something like VSS, because otherwise, what you're trying to do is build software that can predict the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to snapshot the target directories before watching them, like when your service starts up or something, that way when the file change comes through you have the base to compare to.

Comment: If the documents are changed rapidly, then there is no guarantee that you can keep copies in sync if you rely on a FileSystemWatcher i.e. maintain a history as the OP describes.

Comment: So don't rely on FileSystemWatcher, write your own monitor. FSW is flaky anyhow.